# Check how many times specific value in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have an array named $uid.  How can I check to see how many times the value "12" is in my $uid array?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Several ways.

```
$cnt = count(array_filter($uid,function($a) {return $a==12;}));
```

or

```
$tmp = array_count_values($uid);
$cnt = $tmp[12];
```

or any number of other methods.

Comment: `array_count_values()` is not reliable if the count is zero because only found values become keys.

Comment: @mickmackusa how is it not reliable? just do `$tmp[9999] ?? 0` (if 9999 is not found) and it's good to go, I don't know why you would go and reply to everyone using it that it's not reliable just because of the key not existing.

Comment: My comments aim to inform readers who are unaware of fringe cases.  Yes, null coalescing should be used.

Answer (score 12):

Use [`array_count_values()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php). For example,

```
$freqs = array_count_values($uid);
$freq_12 = $freqs['12'];
```

Comment: array_count_values won't work here. I don't do..
    array_count_values($string) //or 12 as $string

Comment: Current versions of PHP don't allow you to use `[]` notation after a funtion call.

Comment: @Hammerite that's stupid, corrected

Comment: `array_count_values()` is not reliable if the count is zero because only found values become keys.

Answer (score 6):

Very simple:

```
$uid= array(12,23,12,4,2,5,56);
$indexes = array_keys($uid, 12); //array(0, 1)
echo count($indexes);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the function [array_count_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

```
$uid_counts = array_count_values($uid);
$number_of_12s = $uid_counts[12];
```

Comment: `array_count_values()` is not reliable if the count is zero because only found values become keys.

Answer (score 2):

there are different solution to this:

```
$count = count(array_filter($uid, function($x) { return $x==12;}));
```

or

```
array_reduce($uid, function($c, $v) { return $v + ($c == 12?1:0);},0)
```

or just a for loop

```
for($i=0, $last=count($uid), $count=0; $i<$last;$i++)
    if ($uid[$i]==12) $count++;
```

or a foreach

```
$count=0;
foreach($uid as $current)
    if ($current==12) $count++;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$repeated = array();
foreach($uid as $id){
    if (!isset($repeated[$id])) $repeated[$id] = -1;
    $repeated[$id]++;
}
```

which will result for example in

```
array(
   12 => 2
   14 => 1
)
```