# PHP: count how many times a random number appears in an array using a for loop?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, random

I am trying to simulate 2000 dice rolls of an 11 sided die (number 2 through 12 on the sides). I have to store the data in an array.

here's my loop where the die is rolled:

```
for($counter = 0; $counter <=2000; $counter++)
{
$die = rand(2, 12);
$int[$counter] = $die;
echo " $die ,";
}
```

^ that seems to work okay as I have 2000 random numbers output.

The next part is where I have trouble. I have to output some of the results. Just to make it simple, let's say I have to output the number of fives that were rolled with an echo statement like:

"*_*_ fives were rolled."

I can't seem to get it to work. For this assignment I HAVE to use a for loop. I tried making a new one with an if statement, and including an if statement in the loop up above. No luck with either. How can I make this work?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960307/check-how-many-times-specific-value-in-array-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this one will solve your problem..

```
 $array = array();
 for($counter = 0; $counter <=2000; $counter++)
 {
     $die = rand(2, 12);
     $array[]= $die;
 }

for($c=2;$c<=12;$c++){
    foreach($array as $r){
        if($c==$r)
        {
            $arr[$c]+=1;
        }
    }
}

foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
{

    echo $value." [".$key."] were rolled<br>";
}
```

Comment: Your welcome... Please upvote or choose it as best answer if that help you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a native function [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) that returns an array using the values of the input array as keys and their frequency in input as values.

You could use that on `$int`, and then use a for loop to go through each of your die options.

If that is not an option, you can copy that functions process by using a for loop to create a new array using the values of your `$int` array as keys, and then increase the value of each key by 1.

Since this is an assignment I don't want to post the actual code I would use. But if you post what you have tried so far I would be willing to look it over and provide corrections/edits to get your code to work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've made some progress - it seems to be working.