# Need Help Counting specific numbers of a PHP array

Tags: php

I am new `PHP` and programming in general I am very lost in how to count the number of times a specific number shows up in an array.

For example I need to count the number of times the number `2` comes up in the array.

I then need to transfer that value to another variable to be able to output it.

I have tried `array_count_value` but cannot seem to get it to output.

This is my array I need to count the number of times each number appears.

I have tried if statements, I have tried everything I have read nothing works, all I get is a blank screen.

```
for($counter=0; $counter <=999; $counter++)
{
$die=rand(2,12);
$int[$counter]=$die;
echo "$int[$counter],";
}
```

Comment: if($array[$index]==2)$counter++;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960307/check-how-many-times-specific-value-in-array-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a counter like this:

```
$total = 0;
for($counter=0; $counter <=999; $counter++)
{
  $die=rand(2,12);
  if($die == 2){
    $total ++; //if its two add 1 to total.
  }
  $int[$counter]=$die;
}

echo 'Total times 2 appeared '. $total;
```

or if you want to count specifically on an array:

```
for($counter=0; $counter <=999; $counter++)
{
  $die=rand(2,12);
  $int[$counter]=$die;
}
$total = array_count_values($int);
$total_for_two = $total[2];
echo 'Total times 2 appeared '.$total_for_two
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$rolls = array();

for($x=2;$x<12;$x++)
{
    $rolls[$x]=0;
}

for($counter=0; $counter <=999; $counter++)
{
    $rolls[rand(2,12)]++;
}
```

Then to retrieve the number of times a number is rolled:

```
echo $rolls[2];
```

This will output the number of times the number 2 is rolled.