# PHP Array Keyword Tally

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
[873] => Array
    (
        [id] => 873
        [email] => 
        [data] => Array
            (
                [#1] => Dmitri Vegas & Like Mike
                [#2] => Hardwell
                [#3] => w&w
                [#4] => alesso
                [#5] => tiesto
                [#6] => nicky romero
                [#7] => dannic
                [#8] => dj alvaro
                [#9] => dvbbs
                [#10] => sandro silva
            )

    )

[872] => Array
    (
        [id] => 872
        [email] => 
        [data] => Array
            (
                [#1] => nervo
                [#2] => axwell
                [#3] => armin van buuren
                [#4] => tjr
                [#5] => w&w
                [#6] => deadmau5
                [#7] => markus shulz
                [#8] => chuckie
                [#9] => alesso
                [#10] => dada life
            )

    )

[871] => Array
    (
        [id] => 871
        [email] => 
        [data] => Array
            (
                [#1] => Noise controllers 
                [#2] => Noise controllers 
                [#3] => Noise crontrollers
                [#4] => Zatox
                [#5] => Zatox
                [#6] => Zatox
                [#7] => Zatox
                [#8] => Hardwell
                [#9] => Noisia
                [#10] => Noisia
            )

    )
```

Basically What i want to do is keep track of the Keywords in a tally type of format, sort of like this

```
Hardwell -> 2

w&w -> 2

tjr -> 1

etc etc
```

I know I have to search through the array with `in_array()` to see how many times the keyword comes up but I am stumped on where to start

I would love to output them in a list according to which value has the highest number, I am kind of stumped. Can anyone start me off on how I would do this?

Comment: This might get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960307/check-how-many-times-specific-value-in-array-php

Comment: Im having a tough time understanding how to use the function, could someone give me a little example?

Comment: your argument shouldn't be `$data` but `$array` in `foreach` for it to work.

Comment: last question i swear! I have a bunch of results like this Dash Berlin was found 17 times, dash Berlin was found 2 times, Dash berlin was found 14 times, They are all the same result, but i guess the letter case is throwing it off, is it possible to make this into one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved using [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/array_count_values):

```
$keywords = array();

foreach ($data as $key => $sub) {
    foreach ($sub['data'] as $key => $value) {
        $keywords[] = $value;
    }
}

$result = array_count_values($keywords);
print_r($result);
```

`$result` will be an array containing all the values and the number of occurences. If you want to also display the number of occurences, you can simply loop through the `$result` array:

```
foreach ($result as $value => $number) {
    echo "$value was found $number times".PHP_EOL;
}
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/76105)

Comment: Your array looks different than mine, how do I change my array to look like that by default?

Comment: Where did you get your array from? How do you generate it? Can you `print_r` it?

Comment: @user2820604: It's the same array. See the `print_r()` output of my array: https://eval.in/76118

Comment: @user2820604: This is how your code should look like: http://codepad.org/DMYQcjp6

Comment: PERFECT! its working, can i order the results to go by which value was mentioned the most?

ie.

Hardwell was mentioned 1000 times
Deadmaus was mentiones 999 times
Dj Dude was mentioned 995 times

etc?

Comment: Christopher Morrissey already told you to use `arsort` for that - just use this function on `$result` array, this way: `arsort($result);`

Comment: Perfect sorry missed that... last question i swear! I have a bunch of results liek this

Dash Berlin was found 17 times 
dash Berlin was found 2 times 
Dash berlin was found 14 times 

They are all the same result, but i guess the letter case is throwing it off, is it possible to make this into one?

Comment: @user2820604: yes, you can replace `array_count_values()` like so: `$result = array_count_values(array_map('strtolower', $keywords));`.

Comment: Okay Okay, one more im really sorry... also I have - above and beyond, above & beyond - anyway to combined those two aswell?

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
  array('data' => array('asd','abc')),
  array('data' => array('abc','cde')),
  array('data' => array('cde','dfe'))
);

$data_array = array();

foreach ($array as $arr) {
  if (is_array($arr['data']))
    $data_array = array_merge($data_array, $arr['data']);
  else
    array_push($data_array, $arr['data']);
}

$new_arr = array_count_values($data_array);
arsort($new_arr);

print_r($new_arr);
```

https://eval.in/76116