# How to compare values in a single foreach loop php

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I am working on opencart.I dont want to allow users to add same product multiple times in cart. for this i have a logic that i want to compare the products in cart. I will get the the product id of each product(how many the user added by clicking add to cart) than i will compare those ids. If they are same i will show them error message else they can carry on. For this logic i have used this code till now.

```
$products = $this->cart->getProducts();
foreach ($products as $product) 
{
$p_id=$product['product_id'];   
}
```

But i dont get that how will i compare 2 product ids in foreach loop. and than add my logic that if product ids are equal show error message.

Comment: you can get idea from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960307/check-how-many-times-specific-value-in-array-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check it at the time when user add a product to cart. To do so modify `add` function in `controller->checkout->cart.php`

In `public function add() {`

**Add**

```
$products = $this->cart->getProducts();
if($products){
 foreach ($products as $product) 
    {
        if($this->request->post['product_id'] == $product['product_id']){
            $json['error']['blabla'] = 'Your warning message.';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Before**

`if (!$json) {`

And display that error  wherever you want to display. That's it.

Comment: can i  show my error in ur case in my cart.tpl? if yes than how?

Comment: This error will arrive when user add any product to cart. But in your cart page you have to create some different code. You can set it in session and can redirect customer to cart page and there show him a message.

Comment: i did it.. actually i used products array got the quantity and checked if quantity >1 plus i created a variable count and incremented it in foreach loop and checked if count>1 than display error. worked fine :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93494/discussion-between-ammar-ul-hassan-and-ved-pandya).

Answer (score 0):

you can get the value of new product id and than compare it like this

```
//get product id to be added
$new_product = "get ID";

$products = $this->cart->getProducts();
foreach ($products as $product) 
{
$p_id=$product['product_id']; 
//compare with new product_id with existing
if ($_pid == $new_product){
echo " Product already exists!!";
}

}
```

Comment: new product id? didnt get this?

Comment: the product that would suppose to be be added but need to be checked if it already exists..

Comment: $products = $this->cart->getProducts(); this gives you multiple rows if there are multiple products so how can i initialise my new product?

Answer (score 0):

```
$products = $this->cart->getProducts();
$exist = false;
foreach ($products as $product) 
{
if ($p_id == $product['product_id']) {
$exist = true;
break;
}   
}

if (!$exist) {
//add product co cart
}
```

Comment: what u doing here? $p_id is not initialized in ur code than how are u comparing it?

Comment: `$p_id` is id of product that customer 'want' add to cart

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$products = $this->cart->getProducts();
$p_id = '';
foreach ($products as $product) 
{
  if($p_id != $product['product_id']) {
    $p_id=$product['product_id'];
  }else{
    echo " Product already exists!!";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you both a unique list of ID's and a list of ID's that needed to be removed to make the list unique.

```
    // get the list of ID's
    $products = $this->cart->getProducts();
    $all = array();
    foreach ($products as $product) 
    {
        $all[] = $product['product_id'];   
    }

    // Flip the array twice to just get the unique ID's
    $unique = array_flip(array_flip($all));

    // Get a list of ID's that were lost
    $difference = array_diff_assoc($all, $unique);
```